# Regular expression for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need some help in regular expression. I am validating the textbox text when updating the records. When i click the update button, the first 5 letters should be equal to CM000 or cm000. How to validate this using regular expression in asp.net. does anyone know validationexpression for this. Let me know .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex - do this instead:

```
bool isValid 
    = textBox.Text.StartsWith("CM000", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If you must use a regex (like for a validation control) then use something like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    runat="server" 
    id="someId" 
    controltovalidate="textBox"
    validationexpression="^(?:CM|cm)000"
    errormessage="Invalid input" />
```

Comment: do i need to use this in javascript?

Comment: @user356973 - It depends, how are you validating the control?

Comment: Nelson - Yes, it would but there is no need to capture if you are never going to use the result.  But you are right, I don't need two groupings here - I will fix my answer.

Comment: Good point on not capturing; I always forget that exists.  Also, just a quick note on RegularExpressionValidator is that it automatically adds the ^ and $ (start/end of text).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678698/net-regularexpressionvalidator-matches-differently-than-regex-class